# Accessing isolated storage of another assembly

Tags: c#, winforms, isolatedstorage

My WinForms application stores various settings in user isolated storage by assembly name, and the assembly is strong named. As I understand it, the isolation is done on the major portion of the assembly version, so changing the assembly version from 2.0 to 2.n has not caused a different isolated storage file to be used.

However, we are about to upgrade our assembly versions from 2.x to 3.0, which will mean that a new isolated storage store will be used. I would like to be able to migrate settings from 2.x to 3.

Is there a way to access the isolated storage of another assembly. I have tried something along these lines:

```cs
var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
var thisAssemblyName = thisAssembly.GetName();
var publicKey = thisAssemblyName.GetPublicKey();

var blob = new StrongNamePublicKeyBlob(publicKey);
var previousStrongName = new StrongName(blob, "appName", new Version(2, 7, 0, 0));

var previousVersionEvidence = new Evidence();
previousVersionEvidence.AddAssembly("appName");
previousVersionEvidence.AddAssembly(new Version(2, 7, 0, 0));
previousVersionEvidence.AddAssembly(previousStrongName);

var scope = IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User;
var container = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(scope, previousVersionEvidence, null, previousVersionEvidence, null);
```

The new application is signed with the same strongname key. I have also tried adding the following attribute to the new assembly:

```
[assembly:IsolatedStorageFilePermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, Unrestricted=true, UsageAllowed=IsolatedStorageContainment.UnrestrictedIsolatedStorage)]
```

However, when I call GetStore, I get System.Security.Policy.PolicyException: Execution permission cannot be acquired.